# AJAX POST two dimensional array to a Zend controller and recieving it

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

Hi in my view I am creating a two dimentional array in javascript and passting it to the update controller as follows :

Array in Javascript

```
item[0][0] = null;
item[0][1] = 1;
item[1][0] = 2;
item[1][0] = 3;
```

`alert (item);` will show `,1,2,3`

Passing it to Zend controller as :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/navigation/update",
            data: item,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

How can I receive this from update controller and assign to it a php array as

```
public function updateAction() {
        $data = $this->_request->getPost();

      //Code should come here
 array(
      item1(
       array(
        value1 = item[0][0] //From javascript array
        value2 = item[0][1]
       )
     )
      item2(
       array(
        value1 = item[1][0]
        value2 = item[1][0]
       )
      )
    )
}
```

I'm a n00b in Zend and any help would be much appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost();
```

Use the following code:

```
$data = $this->_request->getParams();
print_r($data);
```

This will give you the array as you are sending from javascript.

Comment: no it won't, the data has been posted he definiotely needs to use getPost.

Comment: @Andrew getPost also get the other parameter with posted data.

Comment: @Broken Heart - print_r shows only

Array
(
    [module] => admin
    [controller] => navigation
    [action] => update
)

not the array im sending :(

Comment: @NishanCK there is another way, may be not a good, but will work. use the `print_r($_REQUEST);` and check it will give the proper result.

Comment: @Broken Heart - Now it just prints 1 with print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: @NishanCK I think you need to specify the data type to json and convert the array into json the ajax parameter. that will work

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript file declare your array:

```
var item = [[1,2],[3,4]];
```

Then in your ajax call you should modify the data sent to be JSON. Replace the line

```
data: item
```

with

```
data: {data: JSON.stringify(item)}
```

Then, in your controller you can decode the data send to get your array:

```
$data = json_decode($this->getRequest()->getPost("data"));
```

and you have your array.